# jQuery selector ::selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am writing a simple "Flash Cards" application which appears/disappears on a webpage without reloading. I am looking for a way to disable/enable selection through jQuery so that I don't get highlighted areas of the app when repeatedly clicking buttons on it. Is there a way to use jQuery to set background to transparent with ::selection? I am looking for something like:

```
$("*::selection").css("background","transparent");
```

instead of writing this in a css file:

```
*::selection {background:transparent;}
```

PS I am also interested in selecting specific elements instead of using * if possible.

Comment: Why don't you want to set it with css? Then the browser has to do less work.

Comment: I'd like to disable selection only when the app is launched inside the page. When the user exits the app I want to re-enable selection on the page. I am looking for a way to switch selection on and off using javaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
<button>Selection toggle</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.selection *::selection {background:transparent;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('html').toggleClass('selection');  
    if (document.selection) { // IE
        document.selection.empty();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {  // OTHERS
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x43w0sd/2/)

Comment: This is not a reliable solution.  Doesn't always work correctly.

Comment: Can you give us some example?

Comment: Yes, your fiddle is not perfect.  Ir you highlight text, then click the button, it occasionally does not work.  It'll hide some, but not all of the selection background.